# Where to go to delete the old IAB TC String and re-obtain consent in Adsense?

Tags: ads, adsense, gdprconsentform

I have this error at my Google Adsense account:

> We’ve detected an issue on your IAB TC string on one or more of your sites or apps. These errors may affect your ability to serve ads to European users. A detailed report is available for you on the EU user consent page.

The error is 3.3: “The TC string last update date was more than 13 months ago ... CMP should delete the old TC string and re-obtain consent."

Where to go to delete the old TC string and re-obtain consent?

Comment: What is your CMP (consent management platform) ? Theorically, the "cookie" consent should have a 12month life duration.

Comment: I use GDPR offered by Adsense. What should i do to renew this cookie consent?

Comment: Did you find the answer yet @JohnGrischam ?  I'm having the same error issue.

Comment: Not yet @Rich . But it is possible to check which ads have error by clicking first "Go to EU user consent" and then "Download the TCF error report". I changed on my website one of the ad units with the error 3.3 but the other ad unit with 3.3 error results "unknown" so very difficult to act on it. Still receiving the alert from Adsense even though "Last detected date" of the error in my report is of a week ago. Not sure when Adsense with re-scan my website for errors. Will let you know.

Comment: I only have one AdUnit, so I've just deleted it and created a new one, will be interesting to see if that cures it, thanks John!

Comment: One month later and I'm still getting these alerts. Creating a new AdUnit did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following shows that you may have a misunderstanding of how the IAB TCF framework works:

> Where to go to delete the old TC string and re-obtain consent?

The TC String is a standardised format maintained under the IAB's Transparency and Consent Framework that captures a user's fine grained consent choices, which in the case of AdSense with the Funding Choices GDPR consent capture integration is stored within a domain-restricted cookie (which has the name "FCCDCF").

So it's not simply a case of regenerating some property of your AdSense configuration, but rather you need to delete any such cookie containing a TC String containing consent that was captured more than 13 months ago *before* it is presented when loading your ads.

Neither is it a case of regenerating affected ad units because the same violation will then be accumulated on the new units.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76025628/2568535) gives one approach to processing the TC String contained within the FCCDCF cookie and, if necessary, deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

So i still don't know how to delete the TC string but i solved my problem by checking which ads had errors. I did this by clicking first "Go to EU user consent" and then "Download the TCF error report". I changed on my website the ad units with the error (in my case it was 3.3 error). Still received the alert from Adsense for a week after my changes but then Adsense re-scanned my website for errors and the alert did not show anymore.

Comment: AdSense checks for policy violation at the time that each of the ad units is loaded and records the violation against each unit. But the route cause of the policy violation is not specific to the configuration of any ad unit. Therefore regenerating the units ought only to clear the current violations but does not address the cause. The answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76029471/2568535) should address the cause, but I guess time will tell.

Comment: You are right. Even with the new set of ads Adsense 3.3 error message came back after a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks. If you choose to use the solution that I linked to and it works then please let me know and bump the answer. So far for me, able two weeks without a recurrence.