# AdSense IAB TCF Error 3.3: How to delete old string and reobtain consent

Tags: adsense, gdprconsentform

My site, which had been live for a few years now, uses AdSense with its integrated GDPR content feature, i.e. in IAB TCF terminology Google is acting as the CMP.

Over the last few weeks I have got the following message "We've detected an issue on your IAB TC string on one or more of your sites or apps. These errors may affect your ability to serve ads to European users. A detailed report is available for you on the EU user consent page".

When I look at the EU Content page in AdSense I can see download the TCF error report I see the following:

| Domain | Ad unit | Error | Error count | Last detected date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mydomain.com | Unknown | 3.3 | 120 | 15/03/2023 |
| mydomain.com | 9051459592 | 3.3 | 60 | 14/03/2023 |
| mydomain.com | 7113359331 | 3.3 | 20 | 12/03/2023 |

So all errors are to do with consent (according to https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9999955?hl=en) and it looks like I need to "delete the old TC string and reobtain consent".

My question is I don't know how to do this. What steps can I use to do this? I use AdSense directly (both ad units and auto ads) so it looks like I need to ask my users consent but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone advise on what I need to do in order to reduce this error count. My sites get around 25,000 page view a day so the numbers mentioned above are not huge but still It would be better to not have any TCF errors at all.

Comment: @Rob I've address this in an edit to the OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the integrated EU User Consent feature of AdSense, which uses Google's Funding Choices API to provide the Consent Management Platform, does not provide an automatic means to prompt for re-consent when the original consent captured in the TC String reaches 13 months old.

In the Funding Choices implementation the TC String is persisted as a data element in a cookie named FCCDCF, with the TC String itself containing the date that consent was provided. To maintain compliance with IAB's TCF v2 framework, when the AdSense API processes this string and discovers that consent has expired it records a policy violation ("Error 3.3") against the ad units and does not render them. But it does nothing to help resolve the situation beyond providing a somewhat opaque notice that there is an issues that may "affect your ability to serve ads to European users"!

Consequently, earnings will drop over time as an increasing proportion of visitors have TC Strings containing consent that is no longer compatible with the rendering of ad units.

To resolve this issue, the AdSense implementation can be preceded by the following JavaScript (amended to match the domain and path of the FCCDCF cookie for the site) that will extract the TC String from the Funding Choices cookie, parse out the consent date, and then erase the cookie if it determines that consent was provided more than 12 months ago.

```js
/*
 *  Delete the Funding Choices cookie if consent is more than 12 months old.
 *
 *  Version: 2 (2023-12-21)
 *
 *  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76025628/2568535
 *
 */
<script>
  try {
    const nm = "FCCDCF";        // Match name of Funding Choices cookie
    const dm = "mydomain.com";  // Match domain of Funding Choices cookie
    const pa = "/";             // Match path of Funding Choices cookie
    let tc = ('; ' + document.cookie).split('; ' + nm + '=');
    if (tc.length === 2) {
      tc = decodeURIComponent(tc.pop().split(';').shift());
      tc = JSON.parse(tc)[3][0].substring(1,9);
      tc = tc.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
      tc = Uint8Array.from(window.atob(tc), (v) => v.charCodeAt(0));
      let dt = (tc[0] * 2**28) + (tc[1] * 2**20) + (tc[2] * 2**12) +
               (tc[3] * 2**4)  + (tc[4] >> 4);
      if (Date.now() / 1000 - dt / 10 > 86400 * 365)
        document.cookie = nm + "=;path=" + pa + ";domain=" + dm +
                          ";expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
    }
  } finally {}
</script>
```

**Note:** In the above code, replace the string literals for the variables `nm`, `dm` and `pa` with the parameters identifying the Funding Choices cookie. These will depend on your AdSense configuration and will be specific to your installation. You can find these in your browser's developer console by looking at your site's cookies. Additionally, set a reminder to periodically check back here to see whether there has been any important revisions to the code, or (with luck) whether the code has been obsoleted by any improvements made to the Funding Choices CMP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer as it seems the only solution to this issue is on the web. Just one question, how can I find the path of the FCCDCF cookie for my site?

Comment: @NicoCaldo You'll want to use your browser's developer console and find the stored cookies for your site. This will tell you the domain and path that is being set. E.g. with Chrome it's under Application -> Cookies.

Comment: @terry-burton thanks, just a bit lost around nm and pm. Should nm be always FCCDCF? And pm / for every page?

Comment: This solution actually does not work. TC String from Google CMP sometimes is inserting special chars like '-' and atob function fails. How could this be solved?

Comment: @SamSalim I don't know how you have configured AdSense. Examine the cookie planted by Google and match its parameters.

Comment: @jlgsoftware Help folk to help you by providing a complete example of the input and the failure.

Comment: The Base64 chars used by the IAB aren't the same as regular Base64 chars. You can check this official code from IAB and you will see they use chars like '-' .If you have that char in the substring(1,9) the function atob fails. https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/iabtcf-es/blob/master/modules/core/src/encoder/Base64Url.ts

Comment: @TerryBurton You can test with this valid tcstring: CP2-3MAP2-3MAEsACBESAfEoAP_gAEPgAAiQINJD7D7FbSFCwHpzaLsAMAhHRsCAQoQAAASBAmABQAKQIAQCgkAQFASgBAACAAAAICZBIQAECAAAAUAAQAAAAAEEAAAAAAAIIAAAgAEAAAAIAAACAIAAEAAIAAAAEAAAmAgAAIIACAAAhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQQaQD2F2K2kKFkPCmQWYAQBCijYEAhQAAAAkCBIAAgAUgQAgFIIAgAIFAAAAAAAAAQEgCQAAQABAAAIACgAAAAAAIAAAAAAAQQAAAAAIAAAAAAAAEAQAAAAAQAAAAIAABEhCAAQQAEAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAA

Comment: @jlgsoftware The code has been modified to fix this.

Comment: According to this link, the CMP should sort it out for itself but not confirmed. https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/249631889/we-ve-detected-an-issue-on-your-iab-tc-string-on-one-or-more-of-your-sites-or-apps?hl=en

Comment: @RobSedgwick What is the point that you are making? People are seeing an error and their earnings drop continuously as.a direct result. The post that you link to says what exactly? That the system should not have the problem, or that the problem is fixed? People that encounter this issue will find this solution. If they no longer encounter this issue then they won't even begin to look for a solution - so no harm done.

Comment: @TerryBurton the Google support item to my reading says that the error message is a false flag and that the CMP should sort it out itself and earnings shouldn't drop. Like I say I can't confirm that is the case and I am not saying don't use your script. Just info for people to take into account when making a decision.

Comment: @TerryBurton it is also worth checking this: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9999955 - scroll down to "Consent must be reobtained" heading

Comment: @RobSedgwick I believe that the Platinum Product Expert is stating an unhelpful truism: That the CMP must take steps to re-obtain consent once the original consent has expires. If they are in fact asserting that Google's GDPR CMP takes such steps then they would appear to be wrong. The page you linked to says: "For AdSense publishers using Google consent management solutions, there is no action required for 3.3 errors." If you manually edit the FCCDCF cookie to expire the TC String then you can observe that (1) ads no longer render and (2) this does not trigger any kind of re-consent activity.

Comment: @TerryBurton I implemented the code above 7 days ago, but the warning is still showing up in Ad Sense. I did test the code and can verify it parses the timestamp correctly, but seems it's not helping. Any ideas on how to fix it or what additional checks to make? Thanks.

Comment: @pvukovic The code takes a sledgehammer approach of deleting the cookie to drive reconsent. The only thing that could really go wrong is that it doesn't identify the correct cookie. Check that the cookie domain and path identifiers match those that are actually set by Google's CMP.