# Can't delete or change the value of a cookie set on website with PHP

Tags: php, cookies, adsense

So normally I have no problems with setting and unsetting cookies for my website. But for some reason I can't delete this cookie that was set on my website by Google AdSense. Basically I was asking my users for consent, so I could show them ads. But I made a fatal mistake and I would like to ask the users again. But AdSense placed a cookie on my website called `FCCDCF`.

**I use the following code to check for cookies and their value**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE)) {
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    foreach($_COOKIE as  $key => $val)
    {
        echo "cookie name: ".$key."<br /><br />Value: ".$val;
    }
}
```

**This returns the following (I changed the the numbers/letters for safety)**

cookie name: `FCCDCF`

Value: `[null,null,null,["WJGBHDKJKNKSFAAEPA1326467585AkCBIAAgAUgQAgFIIAwAIFAAAAA42567869675425AAAAQQAAAAAIAAAAAAAAEAQ7567464563AAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAA","1~","CP764359-1234-4321-1246-2SDFSDF34566"],null,null,[]]`

Now I would normally think that I could easily delete this cookie by simply using `setcookie("FCCDCF", "", time()-3600);` - but this does not seem to be the case.

Apparently I do not know enough about cookies to find a solution for this. I have searched for hours now and tried a bunch of different solutions for deleting cookies for your website - but nothing worked so far.

My problem is that my mistake cost my 60% of my revenue for this particular site and if this does not get fixed, the website will close, because it's an expensive website to keep running.

Thank you

**EDIT with more details about the cookie and the code I'm using to get rid of it (also see image)**

Cookie details:

Name: `FCCDCF`

Value: `[null,null,null,["CPx4kYAPx4kYAEsACBDADWCgAAAAAEPAAAZQAAAQaQD2F2K2kKFgPi2QWYAQBCujIEAhUAAAAkCBIAAgAUgQAgFIIAwAIFAAAAAAAAAQEgCQAAQABAAAIACAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAQQAAAAAIAAAAAAAAEAQAAIAAQAAAAIAABEhCAAQQAEAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAA","1~","34A656F2-7A38-4C75-88E5-06DDD813736B"],null,null,[]]`

Domain: `mydomain.com`

Path: `/`

Expires / Max-Age: `2024-10-04T20:35:11.000Z`

Size: `343`

Priority: `Medium`

**Important: I have tried to overwrite the cookie by creating a new one**

I have tried to create a new cookie to see if this would automatically overwrite the current one. It doesn't - it just creates a new cookie with the exact same name (see image further down). I created this cookie like this: `setcookie("FCCDCF", "testcookie...", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");`

**So what code am I using to delete the cookies**

First i simply tried this code: `setcookie("FCCDCF", "", time() - (86400 * 30), "/");` - that didn't work.

Next @ProfessorAbronsius asked me to set the cookie with the same value but with the time in the past which I did like this:

```
$CookieValue = $_COOKIE['FCCDCF'];
setcookie("FCCDCF", $CookieValue, time() - (86400 * 30), "/");
```

This is not working either. The cookie is still there. BUT it deletes the testcookie I set.

**Image:**
[image]

**THANK you for your time**

Comment: Where do you run the `setcookie`? It must be before outputting anything. Are you just trying to delete the cookie?

Comment: set the cookie with the same parameters but with the time in the past.

Comment: @user3783243 - I know you think I'm crazy because this should be pretty straightforward. I am setting the new cookie before anything else. Yes I would just try to delete the cookie - but everything I do does not work for this exact cookie called "FCCDCF". Actually I just checked the console I can see that whenever I make a new cookie called "FCCDCF" - it doesn't change the first one but rather makes ANOTHER one so I have 2 cookies called the exact same thing but with different values.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - This is not working either. I know why someone gave me a vote down, because this seems so stupidly simple. But it isn't I don't know how Google AdSense did this, but they did and I can't change it. I can set 100 new cookies, but I can't delete/change he Cookie called "FCCDCF". Actually I just checked the console I can see that whenever I make a new cookie called "FCCDCF" - it doesn't change the first one but rather makes ANOTHER one so I have 2 cookies called the exact same thing but with different values.

Comment: Can you show the full code that you actually have to try to delete the cookie and the full details of the cookie please?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - I just added some more details (in the question itself). Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate that. I hope you can see something I can't

Comment: Is it possible that you successfully remove the cookie and AdSense recreates it? Can you temporarily switch off AdSense, try to remove the cookie and tell us whether the cookie goes missing then? Just a wild thought.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie

Comment: Is the Adsense cookie created with `secure` flag on? Try doing the same (although you might not use a secure connection) or start using a secure connection. Experienced this behavior with normal session cookies for an application. I set them with `secure` on, but not using secure connection, they were 'uncontrollable' by me.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I don't think it recreates it, because if I manually delete the cookie and refresh the page I will see the "consent"-message again. In regards to disabling AdSense, it would be a huge experiment. Because in order for me to do that I would have to delete the website from Google AdSense and reapply the website. And to get applied can take up to several weeks. I'm in a very bad position. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @Piemol As far as I can tell the cookie is not made with a secure connection and the field "Httponly" os not checked either. Secure connection you mean https - right? Thank you for your help

Comment: Niels, I'm happy to help. Unfortunately I do not know the answer either, I was just thinking loudly with the hope that it turns out to be helpful. I wish you the best of luck solving the issue.

Comment: The domains of the cookies are not the same (seeing the image, the second cookie domain name is shifted a bit to the right).

Comment: @Piemol - That is true. That's because one of the domains has a dot in front of it. Like: .example.com instead of just example.com - I did find a solution though and will post it in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution including both PHP and JavaScript.

January 16th, 2024 Google AdSense will introduce this new consent message and force it to all its accepted websites.

**I don't know why PHP can't delete this cookie**

As the user @Pmpkn already addressed in this question; people are already experiencing this problem and can't find a solution. [See the thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75761147/adsense-iab-tcf-error-3-3-how-to-delete-old-string-and-reobtain-consent/76025628#76025628)

**Be aware!!**

I only use this script because I made a fatal error at the beginning of the consent message. I won't force any of my users to consent. But I don't run a charity, so I can't let them use up resources that cost me a lot of money. So they can consent or leave the website.

As you might know, Google let this cookie expire after 13 months. So it's a lot of time with no possibility to ask the users for consent again.

I don't know if this is allowed in the ToS of Google AdSense - so beware of this. Use at own risk. On the other hand. Deleting a cookie on your OWN website should not be a problem in my opinion. I don't know though.

**I introduce the solution**

As simple as this script might seem - it's the only one working. I have tried every other PHP script - and my conclusion is clear: It just can't delete this specific cookie.

```
<script>
var domainName = window.location.hostname;
document.cookie = "FCCDCF=...; expires=Tue, 16 Apr 2019 11:31:56 GMT; path=/; domain=." + domainName;
</script>
```

`var domainName = window.location.hostname;` Creates a variable called `domainName` which will get the exact domain name of the current website.

In the next line you will actually create the cookie with the values you wish. `document.cookie` is telling the browser to create a cookie. The following is just values for the specific cookie. I wan't to delete the Cookie called `FCCDCF` and therefore I name the new cookie exactly that with the value `...` like this: `FCCDCF=...;`

I end the value with a semicolon. After the semicolon, I can then put in another detail of the cookie. In this case I put in `expires=Tue, 16 Apr 2019 11:31:56 GMT;` So the date is 4 years ago and therefore the cookie should delete itself.

Next I put in the path like this: `path=/;`

This next step is very important. I need to use the variable I created and put it in the cookie. But! Look out for the `.` before the variable. The `.` before the domain is very much needed, because AdSense creates the cookie with a dot before it, so the cookie also is included in sub domains.

So it should look like this: `domain=." + domainName;`

**The problem with this script alone**

So this script successfully deletes the cookie called `FCCDCF` and that's great. But the thing is that it deletes the cookie every single time the page is refreshed or the visitor is clicking around on the website. This could be pretty annoying to accept cookies on every page view.

I solved this by looking at the value of the `FCCDCF`-cookie when someone **did consent** and when someone **didn't consent**.

The value of the cookie when someone consents, is around ~800 characters long - give or take.

When someone does not consent** the value of the cookie is only around ~300 characters.

So with PHP I would simply take the value of the cookie and count the characters of this exact cookie. If the characters of the cookie are lower than 600 characters (which means that they did not consent) - I would show the consent message again.

**The complete script that I made**

```
<?php
    $CookieValue = $_COOKIE['FCCDCF'];
    
    $CookieChar = strlen($CookieValue);
    
    if($CookieChar < "600") {
?>
<script>
    var domainName = window.location.hostname;
    document.cookie = "FCCDCF=...; expires=Tue, 16 Apr 2019 11:31:56 GMT; path=/; domain=." + domainName;
</script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Apparently, the following was meta-commentary and was edited out: 

"I am highly disappointed that I would get downvotes for this question. I don't understand why and as people can read and tell - I have tried a bunch of different stuff and done some research also.

And trust me. January 16th, 2024 Google AdSense will introduce this new consent message and force it to all its accepted websites. And there will be a lot of people asking the same questions in the following months.

I feel like this should be included though. Even in a comment. Even the editor didn't upvote this question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a somewhat similar issue to this over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75761147/adsense-iab-tcf-error-3-3-how-to-delete-old-string-and-reobtain-consent/76025628#76025628).

The solution to delete the cookie provided in that post by Terry Burton is written in JavaScript and has a check to ensure the consent was given more than 12 months ago, but it may bring more insight as to how it should be done:

```
<script>
  // Delete the Funding Choices cookie if consent is more than 12 months old
  try {
    const nm = "FCCDCF";        // Match name of Funding Choices cookie
    const dm = "mydomain.com";  // Match domain of Funding Choices cookie
    const pa = "/";             // Match path of Funding Choices cookie
    let tc = ('; ' + document.cookie).split('; ' + nm + '=');
    if (tc.length === 2) {
      tc = decodeURIComponent(tc.pop().split(';').shift());
      tc = JSON.parse(tc)[3][0].substring(1,9);
      tc = tc.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
      tc = Uint8Array.from(window.atob(tc), (v) => v.charCodeAt(0));
      let dt = (tc[0] * 2**28) + (tc[1] * 2**20) + (tc[2] * 2**12) +
               (tc[3] * 2**4)  + (tc[4] >> 4);
      if (Date.now() / 1000 - dt / 10 > 86400 * 365)
        document.cookie = nm + "=;path=" + pa + ";domain=" + dm +
                          ";expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
    }
  } finally {}
</script>>
```

The idea is to create a new cookie with the exact same data (name, domain, path, etc) and set its expiry to the current time so that it gets deleted.

If I am misunderstanding and you already have tried this, do make sure that there are no other cookies saved on the browser with the name "FCCDCF", as they may interfere with your attempt at deleting the one created by AdSense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried this and it's not working either. I appreciate it though. It simply does not delete or edit anything which highly frustrates me.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you tried to delete it in Javascript :

```
document.cookie = "FCCDCF=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
```

And what happens when you Application > Cookies > right-click on site url > clear in the browser inspector ?

[image]